# JDT - AstParser - Get the list of methods which were called for a specific object

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

For example, I have the code like

```
SomeObject1 obj1 = new SomeObject1();
SomeObject2 obj2 = new SomeObject2();
...
obj1.foo();
obj1.boo();
...
obj2.foo2();
obj2.boo2();
```

And I want to get the next output:

> Type: SomeObject1
>
> Name: obj1
>
> Called methods: foo, boo
>
> ==========
>
> Type: SomeObject2
>
> Name: obj2
>
> Called methods: foo2, boo2

thanks

UPD:
I have made a code

```
public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment v)
{
    System.out.println("Declaration of " + v.getName().resolveBinding().getKey());
    return true;
}

public boolean visit(MethodInvocation inv)
{               
    Expression e = inv.getExpression();

    if(e instanceof Name)
    {
        Name n = (Name) e;
        System.out.println("Calling the method \"" + inv.getName().getFullyQualifiedName() + "\" for " + n.resolveBinding().getKey());
    }
    return true;
}
```

> Declaration of Ltest/C:\Test\src\Test~Test;.abc)I
>
> Declaration of Ltest/C:\Test\src\Test~Test;.method()V#a
>
> Declaration of Ltest/C:\Test\src\Test~Test;.method()V#url
>
> Calling the method "replace" for Ltest/C:\Test\src\Test~Test;.method()V#url

For the test code:

```
package test;

public class Test
{
    private int abc;
    public void method()
    {
        int a;
        String url = "ftp://fdh/sdcard/dfsgh";
        url.replace("'", ".");
    }
}
```

The last two keys are equal, that means I have found the appropriate declaration. And it's easy to get types of variables, I won't post this

Comment: Making CFG which consists only from method calls (to check which methods were called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this example](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/), you need, (besides an `AstParser` and the `CompilationUnit` it creates), a [ASTVisitor](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html). then you can have it visit a `VariableDeclarationFragment` for the declaration of the objects and a `MethodInvocation` for. well, method invocations.

Comment: I know this. But how to verify which object we are checking? I mean we got a MethodInvocation, to get appropriate variable creation for a calling object?

Comment: if you "know this" then what are you missing?? please post the code you tried so far. and what is "appropriate variable creation"? you can get the variable through reflesction but your post only mentions printing names. you are unclear.

Comment: this attitude will really get you no closer to a solution. i am honestly trying to help but i cannot understand what you are missing

Comment: I have a code
`public boolean visit(MethodInvocation inv)
{
 Expression e = inv.getExpression();
 if(e instanceof Name)
 {
  Name n = (Name) e;
  System.out.println(n.resolveBinding());
 }
 System.out.println(inv.getName().getFullyQualifiedName());
 return true;
}`
so, from output I see the variable declaration, but how to get from Expression (or Name) VariableDeclarationFragment?

Comment: as i understand it, you want to tie the VariableDeclarationFragment that you got from visiting the variable declaration and the object on which MethodInvocation visit occurs. of course you'll have to save the names and types of all VariableDeclarationFragments you visit and compare the names and types through resolveBinding().  does it make sense?

Comment: Yeah, at this moment I was thinking about this too and have made the code (check the top post)

Comment: so does this mean you got your solution?, if so, plesae be kind and mark my answer.

Comment: Okay, I will. Btw please remove -1 too ;)